# Can I directly pass a Boost ptr_vector list to glBufferData?

Tags: opengl, c

I have a data structure like this:

```
typedef struct vertex_ {
float x;
float y;
float z;
float s;
float t;
}vertex;
```

Then I add to a list called: `boost::ptr_vector<vector> vertices;`

Is there a way to use vertices to provide the parameters for `glBufferData`?

Comment: Are you a C programmer who's recently picked up C++?  There's really no reason to use bloated syntax like `typedef struct X_ { ... } X;` in C++.  `struct X { ... };` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

`boost::ptr_vector` is, underneath the hood, a `std::vector<void *>`.

Not only is it not possible to use the `ptr_vector` to directly supply an input to `glBufferData` (et cetera), but it is a *phenomenally bad* way to store vertex data in general because of the extremely poor cache locality of the data

If you were to use `std::vector<vertex> vertices;` instead, you could pass the address of the first element of the vector to functions like `glBufferData` easily.

Comment: Or in C++11 and onward, `v.data()`, which as a bonus yields a null pointer for empty vectors instead of undefined behaviour.